# Type 'MasterViewController' does not conform to protocol 'CropPerformanceControllerDelegate'

Tags: swift, delegates

On my app there are several views where you input certain values (settings) and so these settings get sent back to the master view using delegates. I already had this setup with 2 other views, and just copied and pasted the required code and changed the variables, however this brought up the error; "Type 'MasterViewController' does not conform to protocol 'CropPerformanceControllerDelegate'"The Code is below:

```
// MasterViewController
class MasterViewController: UIViewController, SettingsControllerDelegate, RainfallDataControllerDelegate, CropPerformanceControllerDelegate {

    // Other variables/functions...

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "MasterToSettings" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! Settings
            vc.delegate = self
        }
        if segue.identifier == "MasterToRainfallData" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! RainfallData
            vc.delegate = self
        }
        if segue.identifier == "MasterToCropPerformance" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! CropPerformance
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func cropPerformanceSettingsSaved(controller: CropPerformance, irrigationResponseFactor: Double, wdImpactFactor: Double, potentialYield: Double) {
        controller.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        irrigationResponseFactorM = irrigationResponseFactor
        wdImpactFactorM = wdImpactFactor
        potentialYieldM = potentialYield
    }
}


// New View
// CropPerformanceView
protocol CropPerformanceControllerDelegate {
    func cropPerformanceSettingsSaved(controller: CropPerformance, irrigationResponseFactor: Double, wdImpactFactor: Double, potentialYield: Double)
}

class CropPerformance: UIViewController {
    var delegate: CropPerformanceControllerDelegate? = nil

    // Other functions and Variables
    @IBAction func updateCropSettings(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Other stuff

        if (delegate != nil) {
            delegate!.cropPerformanceSettingsSaved(self, irrigationResponseFactor: irrigationResponseFactor!, wdImpactFactor: wdImpactFactor!, potentialYield: potentialYield!)
        }
    }
}
```

So this exact same code is used for the settings and rainfallData views and there are no issues, however now on the master view the 'CropPerformanceControllerDelegate' does not seem to be recognised and any uses of the class "CropPerformance" cause the error; "Use of undeclared type 'CropPerformance'". I hope this is enough information, all code to do with the delegate is posted, all other unnecessary variable declarations and functions I left out.

I had looked for other answers and they all said that you need to implement all required methods if you want to conform to the protocols. What exactly does that mean? All of my functions are inside my class and the code works perfectly when I remove the parts regarding the delegate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any evident problem in your sample code. Maybe the problem is in the other stuff that you have omitted.

Comment: I am also super confused, have looked through my code about 20 times, do you know what type of problem could cause such an error? The thing I don't understand is that it works fine with the other views, but then this one gives an error....

Comment: The error message might be misleading. Maybe the "does not conform to protocol error" is the consequence of some other error.

Comment: The thing is when I remove all the code to do with the delegate everything works with no errors, then i put in the code and it doesn't work, the masterView just can't accept the delegate I have no idea why

Comment: My guess is that the problem is in the code you have not included in the example. Maybe if can to build an example that we can compile and that reproduces the problem ...

Comment: Im not sure how to do that, I'm hoping someone can help me from what I have given, the only other option is to share my enitre Xcode file, not sure where/how to do that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to solve the problem as there was no mistake in the code, I simply started from scratch, made a new document, copy and pasted the same code, changed the name to CropPerformance2 and it worked. (It works with any other name except for CropPerformance). This is very strange and must have something to do with that the initial class "CropPerformace" that I had deleted as not completely wiped from the systems memory, at least that is my assumption. In conclusion there is no answer, I simply recreated everything and it worked.